# How does JFrame.setDecoratedLookAndFeel(true) work exactly? Getting some weird results

Tags: java, window, jframe

So I have 3 JFrames. JFrame 1 (aka opts) is for inputting some variables. On OK, it creates JFrame 2 (aka view, a graphical viewing Frame). In the constructor, JFrame 3 (aka manager, for cycling through the graphical views) is created instantly. 
I want them to be Windows-alike decorated with `JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)` (from now on referred to as "it").

A few differtent cases:

1. When I don't set it at all, all JFrames are Windows decorated.
2. When I put it in the "opts" or "manager" constructor, run the project, and click the OK button, all JFrames are Windows-alike decorated.
3. However, when I put it in the "view" constructor, only "opts" and "view" are Windows decorated, but "manager" is Java decorated.
4. But when I put it in a class which does nothing more than read some data from a file, and make some objects out of it, only "opts" is Windows decorated.

How exactly does it work? I want to know why it happens as it happens.

Edit: I can't reproduct case 4, but still, some things happen that I don't understand. Try commenting out some of the "it"s. It'll give some strange results.

```
package test;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame1 extends JFrame {
  public Frame1() {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
      Frame1.setOptions(this);
      JButton b1 = new JButton("hi");
      b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          makeFrame2(2);
        }
      });
      this.add(b1);
    }

    public void makeFrame2(int x) {
      this.dispose();
      new Frame2(x);
    }

    public static void setOptions(JFrame f) {
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.setSize(250, 250);
      f.setEnabled(true);
      f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      new Frame1();
    }
}

package test;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame3 extends JFrame {
  Frame2 link;
  SomeClass sc;

  public Frame3(Frame2 link)  {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    Frame1.setOptions(this);
    this.link = link;
    sc = new SomeClass(25);
  }
}

package test;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SomeClass {
  int x;

  public SomeClass(int x) {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    this.x = x;
  }
}

package test;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame2 extends JFrame {
  public Frame2(int x) {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    Frame1.setOptions(this);
    new Frame3(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you referring to setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated? I can't find the method setDecoratedLookAndFeel you are using.

Comment: sorry about that. Edited

Comment: *"I want them to be ... alike"*  Use one `JFrame` with one `CardLayout`.

Comment: Or I could use UIManager.setLookAndFeel(); But I don't really care how I should've made the application, I want to know why happened what happened. Besides, I need both "view" and "manager" in separate windows as I need to place them independently of each other.

Comment: I think you can use this method at the begin of main method Or use 'JFrame frame = new JFrame(); frame.setUndecorated(true);frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);' for single JFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the oracle java documentation, `setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated` changes the parameter for all newly created JFrames, all existing JFrames are unchanged.

[JFrame Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated%28boolean%29)

Comment: Code added. I removed the useless parts

Comment: You are using the method kind of strange - calling it from within JFrame's subclass constructor won't affect the JFrame, because the super() constructor was already processed before your constructor code. I think you need to call the method before you construct the respective Frame.